# How does std::array brace initialize?

Tags: c++, arrays, list-initialization

Since array has no constructors or destructors and no public non-static member variables, how does array allow brace initialization? Trying to initialize the following type is not allowed:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t num>
class Array
{
    T data[num];
};
```

How can I write this type in a way that it is brace initializable without any constructors or destructors to keep the type trivially constructible and destructible, and without exposing the private array member?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constructor to `std::array` is *implicitly declared*.

Assuming `std::array` is defined as

```
template<
    class T,
    std::size_t N
> struct array;
```

It contains only one member, `T[N]`, which has `public` access.

So therefore it's possible to initialise `std::array` by writing the appropriate syntax for *aggregate initialization*, i.e. by using braces.

Comment: In which way can I rewrite my type to do the same?

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe: Your member is `private` (sorry that was the important bit and was missing from my answer).

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe - `s/class/struct/` all the members need to be public to constitute an aggregate.

Comment: How come std::array's member is not public?

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe - But it is. It has to be an aggregate.

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe it is, its name is just not specified by the standard. Which means you can't access it directly and expect your code to compile.

Comment: How could I do the same?

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe: Replace `class` with `struct` in your class.

Comment: Oh ok I see in every implementation of std::array the underlying array is accessible but the name of the member is implementation defined.

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe: You got it!